# QEMU: No visible cursor when using QXL or virtio

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, virtio

When I run `qemu-system_x86_64` with `-vga qxl`/`-device qxl-vga` or `-vga virtio`/`-device virtio-vga`, the guest has no visible cursor. The mouse works, and items highlight when I hover over them, but I can't actually see the cursor. With standard VGA everything works as expected.

I'm using QEMU 4.2.94 on macOS 10.15.3.

For the guest I've tried both Alpine and Zorin OS Core.

This is what I'm running:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 \ 
    -hda "path/to/my/vm/image" \
    -accel hvf \
    -device virtio-vga,xres=1280,yres=800
```

**Edit:**
I figured out that the problem is that the graphics driver used with `qxl` supports a hardware cursor, but the `cocoa` display doesn’t support it. For now I’ve enabled the software cursor (see [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/21h663/question_can_i_set_my_cursor_to_be_a_software/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=post_body) for details).

Is there any way to add hardware cursor support to QEMU’s `cocoa` display?

---

For anyone who’s interested, this how I enabled the software cursor:

1. Create the directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` if it doesn’t exist already.
2. Create a file in `xorg.conf.d` ending in `.conf` (I named mine `vesa-swcursor.conf`) with:

   ```
    Section "Device"
      Identifier "graphicsdriver"
      Option     "SWcursor" "on"
    EndSection
   ```

Comment: For anyone coming along this in the future, the `Driver "vesa"` line is unnecessary, I'm not sure whether it might be detrimental for performance to add this line.

Comment: @galexite Yes; in fact, you **should** remove the line — with it, the X server will not start, but without it, it starts up just fine with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

`-display cocoa,show-cursor=on` will ensure that the cursor is drawn by the `cocoa` display, however it will always draw the standard cursor, it won't draw a hand or an I-beam or a resize cursor at window edges.